# Implement the Picker as Slot Machine in Native IOS SDK

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I want to make a custom Picker view as follow:

[image]

I Search a lot & google also but I can't able to achieve this.

My picker content is UIVIew not image view.

But the search only gives me Image not for UIView.

**Please Help me to solve this.**

**Thank you,**

Comment: So where you stopped ? Show some code, prove you tried to solve it on your own :) It anyways looks like spam after we closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143759/how-to-make-the-slot-machine-type-in-ios-sdk/20144034#20144034

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski, How to auto scroll picker view for some specific time & make circular picker view?

Comment: [picker selectRow:row inComponent:component animated:YES];

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski, I already knew this but how to make scrolling for i.g. 10 seconds.

Comment: So, do you find new solution ? I'm researching iCarousel.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading this project. I believe its exactly what you are looking for

https://github.com/timburks/iPadSlotMachine

[image]